# How to have dynamic sink in azure dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a dynamic dataflow that gets data using a dynamic query that is pass as a parameter and then I want to upsert and delete in a dynamically defined sink table. I'm having troubles with setting the sink dynamic. is it possible? how can I do it? I see no option to have a dynamic target table. what I was thinking was to add another parameter with the sink tablename and use it.

**High level view of the dataflow**

[Source gets data given sql query ] (OK)

[transformations in the middle] (OK)

[Sink to a dynamic table, that needs to be parameterized but I cannot find a way] (NOT OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parameter in Sink Dataset and then pass the table name as parameter from dataflow activity to Sink Dataset.

Step:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there it is possible, I'm now facing other issues but you can pass the table as a sink parameter in the datafow activity, and in the dataflow your sink will use the parameterized table.

Comment: @Nelssen Thanks for sharing your solution. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Nelssen If your new issues haven't been solved, you can ask another question.

Comment: Hi thanks @Steve Zhao, You are cool! Yeah I solved the issue already but I always have some issue to deal with ahah. but I post in stack overflow as a last resource, I cannot relinquish on own investigation first. By the way do you have presence on the web or something that one can track you? it seems you work with azure It could be interesting to track you. have a nice week

Comment: @Nelssen I'm glad to hear that you solved it. I don't have presence on the web. Have a nice week too.